# Cannot query a document from a sub collection from Firestore collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a specific document nested under collection'users/document'useruid'/collection'items'/'document'documentid'. I keep getting a 'null' value and it errors out:

```
   try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        _loggedInUser = user;
        _userUid = _loggedInUser.uid;
        setState(() {
          // showSpinner = false;
          print(_userUid);
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void getItemDetail() async {
    await _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .document(_userUid)
        .collection('items')
        .document(documentID)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      itemDetails = snapshot.data;
      itemName = snapshot['item_name'];
      itemNum = snapshot['item_num'.toString()];
      itemDesc = snapshot['item_desc'];
      itemLoc = snapshot['item_location'];
      itemQty = snapshot['item_qty'.toString()];
      itemUom = snapshot['item_uom'];
      itemMfr = snapshot['item_mfr'];
      itemStock = snapshot['out_of_stock'];
      lastEditDate = snapshot['edit_date'];
      createDate = snapshot['create_date'];
      imageURL = snapshot['image_url'];

      setState(() {
        dateCreated =
            new DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_US").format(createDate.toDate());
        itemDetails = snapshot.data;
        showSpinner = false;
        stockCheck();
        editDateCheck();
      });
    });
  }
 @override
  void initState() {
    testApp();
    getCurrentUser();
    getItemDetail();
    //   editDateCheck();
    super.initState();
  }
```

```
flutter error output:
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("item_name")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      DocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:29:42)
#2      _ItemDetailScreenState.getItemDetail.<anonymous closure> (package:simmanager/screens/item_detail_screen.dart:77:26)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#<…>
```

The documentid is passed from the navigator on previous page. I have printed (userid, documentid" all the values correctly print.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check whether you're snapshot has any data or null like,

```
if(snapshot!=null)
```

Then you always should check the data inside snapshot is null or not like,

```
if(snapshot.data!=null)
```

Also, in your case you are calling you're data on null object.

I think you need to replace your **snapshot['item_name']** with **snapshot.data['item_name']** for all the item.

You are mistakenly calling snapshot["your_field"] instead of snapshot.data["your_field"] which is causing the issue.

Also, checking null safety while parsing the data from the network is recommended always.

Comment: thanks Jay, i made those changes but im still getting the same error. this worked fine before i created a collection 'items' under 'users', previously 'items' was an individual collection

Comment: Can you please update your question with changes and errors here ?

Comment: added the if statement to check if snapshot != null. for me, snapshot is returning null, but i believe the paths to the firestore documents are correct. no other code changes

Comment: If you are getting snapshot null then there is no meaning of checking and parsing data further. First make sure your query is correct and you are fetching some data. Otherwise parsing data is meaningless.